# Historical lists of prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, math-history

I'd be interested in information about lists of prime numbers that were published (and used by working mathematicians) before the advent of computers.  I know that Pietro Cataldi around 1600 published a list of primes up to ca. 700.  I also know that Gauß mentions in a letter (where he refers to his conjecture about the prime-counting function) "Lambert's supplements to the logarithm tables" which he supposedly read shortly after 1790.  Finally, I've heard about lists of primes published by someone called "Kruger" (Krüger?) around that time.  But that's about it.  I didn't find anything online either, or I used the wrong search terms.

Does anyone have more information?  When were such lists published and by whom?  How big were they?  Also, I wonder if there was a "market" for such lists (as opposed to, say, tables of logarithms).

**Edit:** Oh boy, how embarrassing!  Directly after asking the question I found [this one](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/TablesOfPrimes.html).  It kind of answers my question, but I'll let it stand in case someone has more information to offer.

Comment: http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/RevueHistoireMath/16/pdf/smf_rhm_16_133-216.pdf might be of interest

Comment: Wow, that's more than I would have dared to ask for!

Comment: I've seen Lehmer's table twice in my life. The first time was only a few years after it was published, nicely crisp and white. The second time was a few years ago, yellow like the Declaration of Independence. But now I can't remember whether it listed $1$ as prime or not. I post this as a comment rather than an answer because as a mathematician I am strictly of the amateur variety.

Comment: I continued searching today and found this wonderful site: [http://locomat.loria.fr/](http://locomat.loria.fr/)